# Is this correct grammatically?

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure I would have been able to answer.

Is this present and past combination correct?

Comment: Yes, this is OK.

Comment: What kind of grammatical structure is this? Present+Past?

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your question for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." In particular, you haven't shown any evidence of what research you've done, or explained what you think the specific problem might be. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you take the **[Tour]**. I can also recommend our other site [ell.se], which offers a wealth of information that's useful for both native speakers and learners. :-)

Comment: It's both present and past. The main clause is in the present tense. *I'm not sure (of) X.* But mixing tenses, while often wrong, is not always wrong. It's fine in this case.